# How do I use Criteria to make a join on a date field (in DB2) based on the year

Tags: java, hibernate, db2

I have a java.util.Date field in my Object.  I would like to use Criteria to select all rows that have a date field with a given year.  The SQL would look like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM GAME GM
WHERE YEAR(GM.GAME_DATE) = 2010
```

How can I use Criteria to accomplish this?  Thanks in advance.

```
public Collection<Game> getGamesByDate(Date date){
        Collection<Game> games = null;

        try {       
            session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Game.class);
            criteria ....
                        ...
                        ...
            games = criteria.list();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return games;
    }
```

Comment: An HQL solution might be acceptable as well.

Comment: While this doesn't answer your actual question, you will get MUCH better performance if the resulting query is: "SELECT * FROM GAME GM WHERE GM.GAME_DATE BETWEEN 2010-01-01 and 2010-12-31"  Using the YEAR() function on a date column precludes DB2 from using any index that may exist on the GAME_DATE column.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `Restriction` as follows:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.between("date", startDate, endDate);
```

Where startDate and endDate would be your year with -01-01 and -12-31 (like Ian Bjorhovde said).

If you want to use HQL, the `year()` function is a valid expression in the `where` clause.